# How to enlarge dynamic paint cache size (Blender 2.8)?

Tags: animation, dynamic-paint, cache

I try to create 900-frame animation using dynamic paint in Blender 2.8.

When I try to play animation or bake all dynamics calculations are made until frame #250 and that's all.

Does anyone know where the cache size settings for dynamic paint are (if there are any)?

Or maybe there is some workaround to calculate and bake all the animation?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but did you also set the end-frame in the canvas settings to 900 ?

Comment: @NathanHild. My fault... I searched everywhere, but did not notice the most obvious place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Dynamic paint controls you have **Frame Start** and **End**.

[image]